# Why when I use symetry in sculpting, blender does not finish drawing the line?

Tags: sculpting

I do not use strength pressure and just draw line with stilus.
[image]

Comment: did you try pressing symmetrize in the mirror option

Comment: I pressing on stylus with same power. (but what's the point if the option "pressure" is disabled)

Comment: are you sure that your object is symmetrical? Maybe make it symmetrical: in Edit mode select all and Mesh > Symmetrize then set the axis in the Operator box if necessary